# "TypeError: Illegal invocation" when trying to upgrade from v1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

**Edit:** It seems that this could be related to Chrome v43, I downgraded to v42 and everything works fine.

**Edit:** I've submitted an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12004) on the Angular's Github repo.

It seems that the error gets thrown by 
`return logFn.apply(console, args);` line `12221` in angular.js source.

### Here's a [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911&q=illegal%20invocation&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) to the Chromium bug.

Any tips on what to do now?

---

I'm trying to migrate my app from AngularJS v1.2 to either v1.3 or v1.4 but I'm getting `TypeError: Illegal invocation` on Chrome (tried win, osx and ubuntu).

The stack trace isn't really helping:

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15550)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
    at done (angular.js:10263)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10435)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10376)
```

So this seems something to do with AJAX requests, but I'm also getting:

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at equals (angular.js:1034)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15550)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
    at tick (angular.js:10983)
```

I'm using `$interval` to update a model class (which is a factory and reflected in the views through setting the `$scope.client` to this class):

```
var runTimer = function () {
    self.timeOnline = time(self.timeSoFar);
    self.timeSoFar = Date.now() / 1000 - self.alarmTriggeredTime;
};

$interval(runTimer, 1000);
```

I think there's an issue with `$digest/$apply`. I've spent hours debugging this, but still haven't got a clue on what's happening.

Any pointers into further debugging is much appreciated.

Comment: Coincidentally enough, we've been getting JS errors (not Jquery), on our end with Chrome as recently as last week. See if you can get an older version of Chrome from a month ago and test it?

Comment: Good point. I'm trying that now.

Comment: Weird thing is, these errors don't affect the functionality, they just get spit into the console.

Comment: Yup, this is it. It's working perfectly fine with ```42.0.2311.135```.

Comment: Same problem for me with Chrome 43 and even 44 beta und OSX 10.10.3

Comment: All I know is that when I get that error it's usually because a built in function like console.log was called with the wrong context. If you invoke that function with `this` set to window,  undefined or something else then you will get that error.

Comment: Any luck? I am having the same issue with the following code: 

`element.bind('change', function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;

        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
        });
      });`

Comment: No, nothing yet. I've commented out that console.log statement in angular's source just to go around it for now.

Comment: I also get this with `$scope.myFun = window.history.back;` and there is a similar [angular bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12004)

Answer (score 2):

Between the [angular-issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12004), the [chromium-bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911&q=illegal%20invocation&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), the [webkit-bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20141) and the (I dont even know what this is) [something-Webkit-issue](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2014-December/650800.html) it would *appear* as if everyone (well, mostly everyone) is throwing their hands in the air. Perhaps I'm being judgemental/plain wrong in saying that.

Anyway, I wasn't able to get the `window.history.back` case to log without causing an `Illegal Invocation` but I was able to do `console.log.call(window, 'x')` with the following 'snippet:'

```
(function() { console.log = console.log.bind(console); }());
```

(taken straight off of the last link there, **thanks Brian!**)

Just slap that out in the top of your HTML document/wherever you want (I guess).

---

*I'm **super** curious as to what would happen if you were to run that @Ignas.* I cannot seem to replicate the issue you are presenting with a Factory binding to `$scope` and running that `$interval` of yours.

Would love to see if it holds any effect (albeit, not a functional one but more so a *decorative* one, I suppose).

Sidenote; *Me being the newbie I am, I was just informed by my peers that console.log.call(window) shall indeed throw an Illegal Invocation error, so that is a non-issue afaic. Still curious as to if this would hold effect on the `logFn` inside Angular.*