# Angular.js Illegal invocation on copied File object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Well, there is not really much to explain.
https://jsbin.com/raqajelufu/edit?html,js,output Illegal invocation exception is raised on any File object property access after being copied with angular.copy.

Is there any workaround, which would make watching for File object possible, considering $watch is using angular.copy internally according to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope?

Comment: Have you tried with $watch or only calling copy explicitly as in your example? You can probably work around it by providing a destination to copy, as the problem seems to be when it tries to create one internally using Object.create(...), though I don't personally know how to workaround if you get the error with $watch when it calls copy itself..

Comment: I think your problem isn't with copying but with instantiation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript

Comment: Calling `var f = new File([],"")` and then `f.name` does not yield an error, so I still think the problem is with copying

Comment: @aw04, yes $watch throws that error as well. Here is an example to show that https://jsbin.com/gatumewuwa/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Which browser(s) are you seeing the issue on?**

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578722/typeerror-illegal-invocation-when-trying-to-upgrade-from-v1-2/) was asked a while ago which concluded that it *could* have to do with Chrome v43.

Some resources related to the issue:

- [chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911&q=illegal%20invocation&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
- [webkit bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20141)
- [webkit bug 'conclusion'](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2014-December/650800.html)
- [angular issue regarding .copy and .equals](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12004)

*Supposedly*, Chrome v43 does **not** like the following in the `angular.copy` [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L827):

```
var emptyObject = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source));
```

You could try any of the following to see if it suppresses your errors (regardless of your browser of choice):

- Dont use `angular.copy`, by avoiding deep watches a la `$scope.$watch('', fn, true)`([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/toqofalixi/1/edit)) and go for something like [_.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dufelocaga/1/edit?html,js,output)) from lodash when you need to make a deep copy of something.
- Step back to Chrome v42 (if you are on v43).
- Step back to Angular 1.2.28 where `angular.copy` does not call the above line. [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/37310e024d6dd6894ed3ac6a3e2a84da6d6bbd1a/src/Angular.js#L792) ([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/loyogofubi/1/edit?html,js,output))

---

If you want to watch deeply but avoid `angular.copy`, I would do something like this (with the help of [lodash.merge](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)):

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return _.merge(src, dest);
}, callback);
```

[yet another jsbin](https://jsbin.com/telulofoni/1/edit?js,output)

That way you wouldn't call `angular.copy` and you would still have a 'deep watch' setup. Bare in mind, this is a very naive example and I have not tested it thoroughly but I think you could make it work very similarly to an angular deep watch with minimal effort.

---

**Disclaimer:** *I haven't really dug that deep into what is actually going on the `angular.copy` source, the `console` and/or Chrome v43. It is somewhat of a gray area, but with the above suggestion(s) I have yet to trigger an Illegal Invocation.*